# Safari 5.1.5 and Flash Content

Tags: flash, youtube, safari-5

I am having trouble with flash content while using Safari 5.1.5. I am using MacBook (early 2008) and Mac OS X version is 10.7.3. There is no extension installed and flash version is 11.2 r202. Here is a basic scenario that I generally experience on Youtube:

- When a click a link on Youtube or any other website redirecting to youtube, the video doesn't show up at first, but it starts playing after refreshing the page. Initially I see only black video screen with loading animation. This basically causes my youtube playlists don't work, because after a video finish playing, the next one comes, but not runs.
- Another thing is when there is flash content on a page/tab, I need to open that tab and wait it to load and run. Otherwise, let's say I clicked a bookmark linked to radio listening page and change tab, Safari doesn't load and run it.

My question is 'Is it just me, or are there other people having similar problems so that I can report a bug?'